# Method in model that filter by user

Tags: python, django

My model:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), null=False, blank=False, max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), null=True, blank=True)
    is_favourite = my_method()

class FavouriteDocumentUser(models.Model):
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('document', 'user',)
```

I need a field 'is_favourite' that is true if exist in FavouriteDocumentUser a row with the id of the document and the id of logged user.

So the problem is: how can I get the current user in a method of the model?

I'm using these models into django rest framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, because Django ORM is not aware of Django authentication. The *current* user is available in the `request` object, which is only available to your views. You need to pass your `request.user` to your model method. For example:

```
class Document(models.Model):
   ...

    def is_favourite(user):
        return self.favoritedocumentuser_set().filter(user=user).exists()
```

then you call this method from your *views*:

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    if mydocument.is_favorite(request.user):
        ...do something...
```